# nhibernate testing strategy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate

I'm thinking of throwing away all repository classes in my next project and use `ISession` directly in my service classes. The reason to this is that my repository classes just tend to forward calls to the ORM (i.e. have no real logic).

The biggest disadvantage with this is that it makes Unit testing harder and I'm wondering if there are any other ways to test my services without a database (no in-memory db like sqlite please)? Is it a bad idea to mock `ISession`?

Or should I just stick with the thin repository classes?

Comment: I don't understand the 'without a database' requirement; suppose you have something like that in your service class: `Session.Query<User>.Where(u => u.Domain = domain)`. Wouldn't you want to test this query to see that it produces the correct SQL and correct results? How would you do that?

Comment: @sJhonny: Integration tests and not unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might look easy to mock `ISession`, but I found it hard to do a proper mock. Especially if the LINQ extensions methods are used.

I will stick to repositories. It's easier to understand what's expected of an repository method than a generic interface such as `ISession`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a bad idea to mock ISession?

No, it is not a bad idea. It is what you could do in order to test your service classes if they depend on ISession. There is a design smell though because your service classes depend on NHibernate but I guess that you could live with.

Comment: Please elaborate on why a ORM dependency is a design smell? (they are not WCF service classes)

Comment: @jgauffin, it's because the service layer should be ORM agnostic. It's the DAL layer that is specific to some database or ORM (if you use any). If in the future you decide to change data access strategy or ORM you won't need to modify your service layer. But if this is something that you do not intend to, as I said, you could live with an ISession in your service layer.

Comment: @jgauffin, in an ideal world where you want to separate everything you could have a DAL layer which is specific to some ORM provider that implements your repository interfaces providing simple atomic operations on your models and then the service layer takes those repository interfaces as constructor arguments.

Comment: @jgauffin - that is certainly debatable. For instance, refer to this Oren Eini blog post for an argument against repositories: http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton